# Null value resulting a particular datetime when changing datetime format with strtotime() and date()

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am converting this '29-08-2013 12:27:04' datetime to this format '2013-08-29 12:27:04' using this code

```
$insert_dts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($this->input->post('insert_dts')));
```

But the problem is; whenever the value goes null it results in  '1970-01-01 00:00:00'.

Since I am using the `$insert_dts` to enter into the db it was entering this value(1970-01-01 00:00:00) rather than '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in a datetime field in mysql db.

I know this can be solved with a if else checking whether the `$this->input->post('insert_dts')` was null or not.

Is there any other solution without checking each one?

Comment: no, whats the problem about checking each value?

Comment: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 is zero in the epoch, which is used in unix_timestamps. the timestamp counts the seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. so its totally correct, and there is no other way the checking the value beforehand in this part of the code. Another possibility would be to handle this while inserting in to the DB inside the SQL-Statement

Comment: @steven nothing, just asking if there is anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Using a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` could be a much cleaner way.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/create-trigger.html

Not sure you consider it different from "checking each one".

Comment: I would use TIMESTAMP since it offers default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which is automaticly dated during INSERT.

Comment: but if I use the trigger, can i insert the value 1970-01-01 00:00:00 ?

Comment: Everytime you will insert `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, you will transform it into `0000-00-00 00:00:00` no matter what. Could `01-01-1970 00:00:00` really be a possible intput ? If so, you will need to check it using PhP

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime($this->input->post('insert_dts'));
if($time == 0)
$insert_dts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
$insert_dts = $this->input->post('insert_dts') ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post('insert_dts'))) : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```